# my android phone can't access to any google related sites and services

Tags: wi-fi, google

I just recently bought a brand new asus zenfone go, everything is fine until I shut off my wifi and left home. I subscribed to a mobile data plan, of course.

but i can't access any google related website or apps at all using the mobile network. you name it, youtube, gmail, playstore, even www.google.com on the browser. But when i tried connecting to the wifi, I have no problem accessing them.

I tried tether my phone's internet connection on my PC using  a usb cable. Eveything works fine, google.com.. gmail.com.. youtube.com.. Only on mobile network on this phone, I can't access all google services. I tried clear data and clear cache of the google play services, it wont fix it.

I even tried manually setting up the date and time. still no.

I almost gave up googling for hours. hope anyone who experienced this help me please! as for now, if i need to access the gmail apps, i need to use wifi.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your device has the correct band and frequency support for your carriers 3G/4G data service, On the Zenfone 2, only SIM 1 allows data connection, and you must have the APN information set correctly, which sometimes needs to be done manually . Contact your carrier for the correct APN settings.

Comment: The problem is that only google services is not working. Others are working fine. For example, google.com won't open. But engadget.com load just fine. And this only happened on mobile data.

Comment: As for the apn, is already check and it is already correct. As internet is just working fine. Only google access i have problem with. Isn't that weird?

Comment: Do you have a VPN configured on the phone? And do any Google Apps work like Maps, or just the Web page won't load?

Comment: yes i do.. its already configured correctly as my telco sent me the configuration for the phone automatically... no, nothing related to google works on mobile data.. but on wifi they all working fine.. so i suspect this have something to do with the apn maybe?

Comment: I contacted my carrier and apparently the apn setting set by them automatically is wrong.. they asked me to edit the apn setting here and there and its finally working. thanks.