# Internet is not working except Whatsapp application

Tags: internet, xiaomi

In Xiaomi Mi 2 mobile, I can't connect to internet except Whatsapp application which is running smoothly.
I can't open any website on any browser also Gmail and other apps are not working.

This happened after phone reset and changing sim.
I called AirTel customer care, they say that internet is fine from their side.

Please suggest something to fix the issue.
Thanks

Comment: Have you confirmed that your plan has access to use internet *outside of WhatsApp*? Are you by any chance using [WhatsApp-only plan](http://www.airtel.in/whatsapp/?cid=social21491444)?

Comment: Have you confirmed that the problem persist with both Wi-Fi and mobile data? Related: [Some apps cannot access the internet](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/102248) (happens only on Wi-Fi)

Comment: Related: [my android phone can't access to any google related sites and services](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/134174) (for mobile data only).

Comment: Yeah, There is full fata plan.
Btw I found that in APN setting, proxy was set. I removed it and net working now.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I finally found that proxy was set to some ip in APN setting.
    I removed proxy and saved APN setting. And Internet is working fine now.

> Mobile Networks > Access Point Names > open the one APN > delete the
>   content in Proxy

Comment: Removing the Proxy worked for me! Mobile Networks > Access Point Names > opened the one APN I have > deleted what was under Proxy. Hope this helps!

Comment: removing proxy under APN names in Mobile Networks, worked great for me on redmi note 3 32 gb

Comment: This worked for me on Samsung S8 as well

Comment: You saved me, Thanks. Xiaomi Redmi note 8

Answer (score 1):

select mobile office instead of airtelgprs
 in the column of access points. it will work

Answer (score 0):

First check the data settings and allow all apps to get connected.
next change access point names.

watch it
https://youtu.be/RRfSZkLQ3-w